# Could a faulty household electrical system be mildly damaging my two (same model) laptops' batteries? Mysterious laptop charging problems

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, grounding, charger, laptop

I've got two laptops of the same brand and model. I got their two original chargers, which are the same model as well, with same specs.

I've been living in my current apartment for 2 years now and during that time both laptops have had charging problems:

- Laptop A: I've had to change the battery twice (so I've had 3 batteries already). The first time was in August 2021 but it had been failing for months. The second time was just this week (December 2022) and it had been failing since before summer. The problem was that the battery did not seem to hold much. It was not fully dead since when I unplugged the laptop after several hours charging, it did not immediately turn off but it immediately complained about low battery levels and turned off after a couple of minutes or less. I think the previous battery did not work at all but I am not 100% sure.
- Laptop B: Was working fine until one day about half a year ago it just stopped charging. No matter which one of the two chargers, it did not charge. I was able to use it until the fully charged battery ran out. The surprise was that when I sent it to the manufacturer, it worked for them. They plugged it in, and it charged. They had it there for days doing battery tests (plugging and unplugging, letting it run out, etc.) and did not find any problem. I got it back home without any repair needed and it works now.

My flatmate has a MacBook, and he has not had any trouble. We don't usually connect it to the same sockets as my laptops. We (obviously) have other electronic devices (PS5, TV, router) but have not had any other problems. I spent over a year charging my laptops on a specific power strip, I'm now trying without it just in case it was that (although I would not know if it could be that.) Nonetheless, I am plugging them in to the same socket the strip was previously plugged in to.

I suspect it might be both the charger(s) and my household system but I don't know much about electrical systems nor laptop electronics. Both laptops have been looked at by the manufacturer although I do not know at which level they checked.

I believe we do not have a correct ground wiring. The system was remade when we moved in but the grounding made the breakers blow when we used the oven so, since they could not find why, I believe our "amazing" electrician just disconnected the grounding.

We checked our plugs' voltage once to see if the differences between the (hot - neutral - ground) were normal, and they seemed normal.

Could my flatmate's charger be of better quality and be protecting its laptop from fluctuations mines are not? I believe his laptop charger does not have a grounding circuit, if that could be a factor. The TV and the PS5 cables also have 2 prongs, without grounding. My laptops have the 3 connectors. (I'm in Spain so we've got european sockets.)

Does anyone have an idea of what could be happening? Could there be some voltage fluctuations that do not directly damage the laptop but damage the charger transformer or make the charger mildly damage the battery?

**Update:**

Today we have been taking some measurements and there's some really weird things going on with our grounding system. Here's what we got:

- The main ground wire, when disconnected from the housing wires, has a voltage of 5V. (By only touching the voltmeter with one prong, the other one touching nowhere, so I don't know for sure this is a meaningful measurement.) We do not know if it is really connected to the ground (I suspect it is not) and/or if it is common with our neighbours ground wire.
- We've got different circuit breakers for different parts of the system (lights, wet, etc). We took one of the plug sockets out and found that:

  - Between the neutral wire and the live wire there are 233V, between the neutral and the ground there are 0V, and between the live and the ground there are 233V. But: **if we turn off one of the circuit breakers (not the one that controls this socket) then there are only 180V between the live and the ground, and around 67V between the neutral and the ground**.
  - When this switch is off, this socket's ground wire shows 5V when only using one prong (again, not sure what this means.) We tried different sockets grounding prongs and they also showed values between 5 and 11 that varied up and down depending on whether the circuit breaker was on or off.
- On the general fuse/circuit breaker box, we disconnected all of the grounding wires from the general one and checked each one separately (again, using only one prong, the other on the air). Some of them showed voltages ranging from 0V to 7V.
- We found that by disconnecting the microwave, these voltages varied considerably. One of the grounding wires went from 7V to 3V. However, with the microwave disconnected, we still see the 230V to 180V difference mentioned above and there is still some voltage on the individual ground wires. The microwave is not connected to the circuit breaker we were switching on and off above.
- Our LED bulbs last just a few months, which does not seem normal either. They are wired to the seemingly faulty circuit breaker. I've been told their electronics could be being damaged similar to my laptops, although these light bulbs don't have grounding

It really seems there's more than one part messed up, since many different parts of the system are producing weird measurements.

So,

1. Can anyone explain why would the voltmeter detect voltage when only one prong touches a wire? I understood voltage as a difference between two points so I don't know how to interpret that.
2. Is it normal that the main ground wire shows 5V?
3. It is clearly not normal that the voltage goes from 230V to 180V by only disconnecting part of the system, right?

For now, I will cover the grounding prongs of my laptop chargers so they are isolated from these grounding inconsistencies.

Comment: Your household electrical system can't affect the life of batteries through the charger, the power from socket is either there or it isn't.

Comment: (`what could be happening?` Electrickery!) I expect the laptop battery management built-in to the laptop. What's connected to mains and the laptop isn't a *battery charger*, but a (somewhat) constant output voltage *power supply*. While performing in spec of the laptop's PS input, there should be no effect on the battery whatsoever.

Comment: "I believe our "amazing" electrician just disconnected the grounding" - that's extremely worrying. You need to get it sorted out ASAP.

Comment: @Finbarr I know, I'll try contacting the landlord. We knew it was dangerous but had not pressured him to avoid causing issues (we do have some good rent conditions right now and did not want to mess this up). Seeing these weird measurements it is clear something is wrong so I'll contact

Comment: @Justme it is quite clear to me that somehow it can. The transformer is just another electronic device right? can't it be affected by the inconsistent measurements between the grounding and the live/neutral? If it works by considering that this difference should be normal, maybe?  It is clear that something happens and the fact that some problems were solved when the laptop was charged somewhere else makes me quite sure is due to our sockets. These weird measurements make me even more sure

Comment: @Justme however, I must say I cannot observe any weird measurement on the charger's  output no matter the combination of switches, it always outputs 19V

Comment: @raquelhortab Not really. I mean the earth ground is important for many reasons, but many people use laptop power supplies in old houses that have ungrounded sockets. If it did matter in regard to charging, surely a lot more people than only you would have problems charging. The only thing might be a loose neutral or live wire so it does not charge at all.

Comment: sure, but not having a ground wire is not the same as having one which voltage difference with the neutral is not zero, or is it? @Justme

Comment: @raquelhortab You measured voltages with only one multimeter probe connected. Your measurements are invalid. If some wire was disconnected and floating, you are measuring capacitvely coupled voltages. Two conductors with insulation in between is a capacitor, so live wire will affect a nearby unconnected wire. Unless you are an electrician or otherwise legally allowed to do mains electrical work in your apartment, consider stopping immediately.

Answer (score 2):

From what you are describing, I'd say that you have no ground at all in your appartment.

The ground wire normally has no function electrically - no current should ever flow through the ground wire.

The ground wire is a safety feature of the wiring system.  It is there to protect you when certain malfunctions happen.

The lack of ground shouldn't cause damage to your equipment.

The lack of a ground can mean injury or death to you if some piece of equipment that expects a safety ground malfunctions.

1. Get a real, qualified electrician to check the wiring and fix the ground and any other problems that may exist.
2. Stop playing in the circuit breaker box.  You stand a good chance of injuring or killing yourself.
3. Do not reconnect anything in the circuit breaker box that you may have disconnected.
4. Stay away from the circuit breaker box and do not go near it until an electrician has fixed things.

Without having seen what you've done, I'd suggest you not use or touch any electrical appliances in the appartment until the electrician has fixed things.

---

- Connecting one probe of a voltmeter and waving the other around in the air doesn't tell you anything.
- Connecting one probe to a disconnected ground and the other to various parts of the electrical system doesn't tell you anything useful.  There will be a voltage, but it will not deliver any current.

Comment: How does this address the question? Yes, there is an obvious unrelated problem, but will fixing that solve the problem?

Comment: It directly addresses the question: "The lack of ground shouldn't cause damage to your equipment."

Comment: It was more important to stop the OP from further experiments in the fuse box.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Let's hope Darwinian evolution via learning from others happens rather than a Darwin Award.

Answer (score 1):

The item you refer to as a charger is not actually a charger: it is a power adapter which takes in the AC mains electricity and outputs DC at a lower voltage which is suitable for the laptop. The input and output are isolated from each other. The laptop itself contains the battery charging circuitry.

(Replacement laptop batteries are not all of the same quality: check independent reviews before making a purchase.)

So, there is no connection between the poor quality of your household electricity supply and the lifetime of your laptop batteries.

The **household supply being dodgy** is a separate issue and **should be fixed as soon as possible** for safety's sake. Laptop batteries do have a finite lifespan which also depends on how heavily they are used.

Comment: I see... So it is a coincidence that both things are messed up, and also a coincidence that laptop B started working again when plugged elsewhere? Cool, I now got two nightmares instead of one

Comment: @raquelhortab The household supply being dodgy is a separate issue and should be fixed as soon as possible for safety's sake. Laptop batteries do have a finite lifespan which also depends on how heavily they are used.

Comment: @downvoter How does this not address the question? Yes, there is an obvious unrelated problem, but will fixing that solve the problem?

Comment: I agree, I balanced it out by voting up